# Integrate a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I know this is a novice question, but I'm new at Matlab and am trying to integrate a function  for n=0, n=1, etc.. This is my code so far:

function x = t^n*(t+5)^-1
int(x,t=0..1)

And I keep on getting this error:

Error: File: a02_IX.m Line: 1 Column: 15
Unexpected MATLAB operator.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling  int(x,t,0,1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it this way:

```
function x = t^n/(t+5) int(x,t=0..1)
```

I think raising the term in parentheses to the -1 power reads badly.  Maybe MATLAB is confused, too.

What's the value for `n`?  Don't you need to specify that?

It helps to know the answer before you start.  This is easy to integrate analytically.

The function looks like this for `n=2`:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+t%5E2%2F%28t%2B5%29+t%3D0..1

Here's the integral, both indefinite and definite:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+t%5E2%2F%28t%2B5%29+from+t%3D0+to+1

Comment: I tried rephrasing it like that, and even plugging in a random number for n and I still got the same error :(